# Ajax, DOM and submit = page refresh

Tags: php, laravel

I've have checked similar questions, do a lot of research, ask several people during 2 months but I still have a problem, I sometimes (not always, and I cant reproduce) get a page refresh when submitting the DOM form [here in action](https://insights.hotjar.com/r?site=549427&recording=1278277953&token=bf89c8801442b9ccd03df766d224e002) Here you also have the link for the text website at the bottom. After clicking it should go to the payment gateway, not refreshing.

So in other posts I saw that it's a good idea to put `e.preventDefault()` and `return false` which I did, to avoid form refreshing, but I still get a refresh! Any idea what else to try? Did I do something wrong?

I think is something to do with the DOM, submit or ajax.

Non sense.. any tip of what should I do. And why is just to 10% of the users (with different explorers)

The first ajax output which it's read by the below code:

```
  'action' => 1,
  'url' => 'https://sis.redsys.es/sis/realizarPago',
```

`$('#form-p`ayment').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

```
        var data = $('#form-payment').serialize();

        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ url('/pago') }}",
            data: data,
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': "{{ csrf_token() }}"
            },
            method: 'POST',
            timeout: 20000, // sets timeout to 5000 = 5 seconds
            retryCount: 0, // start retry count
            retryLimit: 1, //will let you retry a determined number of times
            beforeSend: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                if (data.action == 1) {

                    //delete if the form it's already there
                    $('#TDCform').remove();

                    var form = $('<form id ="TDCform" action="' + data.url + '" method="post">' +
                        '<input type="hidden" name="Ds_MerchantParameters" value="' + data.params + '" />' +
                        '</form>');

                    $('#form-payment').after(form);

                    $('#TDCform').submit();
                    //$('#form-payment').off();
                } else {

                    var errorString = 'There's and error.';
                    (".taberrors").html(errorString).fadeIn(2000);
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: $('.taberrors:visible').offset().top - 100
                    }, 1000);

                }
            },
        });

        return false;
    });
```

Comment: try using   `$('#form-payment').on('submit', function(e)`

Comment: you could do it with a button instead of a submit field `<input type="button"` and forget submitting it altogether.  But then the form won't work without JS, also it might be better to get the URL right from the form action `url: $('#form-payment').attr('action')` this way your not maintaining it in 2 places in your code (I'm assuming the form also has this `{{ url('/pago') }}` deal as the action).  That's my  2 cents.

Comment: thanks so much, I'm going to try and see the results, if that solve the problem a I'd like to pay you guys, too much time spent on this during last months

Answer (score 1):

### **Solution 1**

Change this:

```
$('#form-payment').submit(function(e) { e.preventDefault();
```

To this:

```
$('#form-payment').on('submit', function(e) { e.preventDefault();
```

This have solved my similar problem with *click* event..

I've changed this:

```
$('#update').click(function(e) {
```

To this:

```
$('#update').on('click', function(e) {
```

And this have solved my problems

### **Solution 2**

Add the code into this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    //INSERT CODE HERE
});
```

Comment: thanks so much, I'm going to try and see the results, if that solve the problem a I'd like to pay you, too much time spent on this during last months